# MySql General Query Log

Tags: mysql, linux

Does restarting the **MySQL service** on **Linux**, disables the already enabled general query logging?

There was a log file getting generated inside the data folder, and it was growing exponentially. The db has 100 requests per minute.

Initially i guessed, some transaction had broken in between, that made the logs to swell.
So i restarted the service, which stopped adding to that log file.

I checked the global variables and got to know the path was assigned for general_log_file. But now it was showing 'OFF'.

Hence my query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a common issue that people will set configuration of MySQL through dynamic (global) variables and forget to set the variables in the options file (my.conf). In that case, when the server is restarted, MySQL will revert to default settings.

The default setting for [`general_log`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_general_log) is `OFF`. To immediately enable the general query log, set the global variable to `ON`. Then set the value for `general-log` in your `my.conf` file to ensure that the setting is applied whenever you restart MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

No,  Restarting the server doesn't make the binary logs to OFF...

It may be the case that you changed the configuration file before and now restart takes that file...

Comment: Thats what i thought, but i didn't find anything in the config file. So it has to be default off. But then again why the file was getting created? And, then at restart it stopped.

Comment: I think earlier the file has the option of general log...
you or someone editing it but not restarted the server..

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will start with whatever options are in the file configuration. If you switched any of the global server variables before, they will be reverted to what is set in the file.